# How to politely ask for verification delay?

Tags: conversations, politeness, online-interaction, email, personal-information

I've worked in a market. Suddenly they stopped my work for verification purpose. They requested me to provide a student ID card. I've sent a scanned copy of my Student ID card for verification. One week has gone still now they have not sent any confirmation email. How do I politely and without any grammatical error ask them about my verification delay?

I thought I could say something like this but I am unsure of the phrasing:

> Hi Admin, Why are you pending my Student ID verification? Why do you
>   taking so long to verify my ID?

How can I politely ask them what is taking so long for them to verify my ID?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to IPS. Asking for good ways to do something isn't a good fit for IPS, as it's likely to attract opinion based answers. I therefore allowed myself to edit your question and slightly change it to "how to politely ask why such a delay on my ID checking". Feel free to edit or rollback if I got you wrong, and don't hesitate to reach out if you have further questions or need any help. Have a great time among us!

Comment: This looks like a phrasing request which aren't a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 4):

How about "Hi (name), I hadn't heard from you regarding the student ID photocopy which I sent to you, and I wanted to make sure that you had received it.  Have you?"

This gives them the opportunity to explain the delay, but does not sound accusing or complaining.

It might just be that they are slow in responding, or it might be that there is a problem.  Either way, you can't *make* them answer your question, you can only remind them that you are waiting and give them the opportunity to respond.

You didn't mention whether the request was made in person (by a specific person who you have access to) or via email.  Either way, I have found that the best way to get my questions answered is to be polite (as I can see that you are already aware) and to make it easy for them to answer (by contacting them).

Another incentive is to make them feel like they are doing you a favor by answering. You could add "I don't mean to be a bother, but I have been feeling  anxious about the situation, and I was wondering if there was something more I needed to do in order to comply with store regulations".  This asks for help, and shows the person in charge that you are willing to comply with their rules.  Both helpful things.

It may be that whatever is delaying the confirmation has to do with your official status.  They might be afraid you are an illegal immigrant.  It might be irregularities with your paperwork, or some official requirement that is yet to be filled.  If any of these are the case, the delay may just be the result of the fact that whenever the government is involved, there will be delays.  It's frustrating, but there isn't anything you can do and it might be that there's nothing they can do, either.

Comment: Hi Francine, possibly the downvote is because answers on IPS [should have backup](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/), could you add that? Either personal experience (like "I did something similar in X situation, the outcome was Y") or giving an external reference works for that.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to provide backup for what seems to be a simple request for grammatical assistance.  I'm a native English speaker and I do a lot of writing.  I'll see if I can give a better explanation, @Em C, thanks for pointing it out.